# String to date sometimes the full date exists sometimes I only get year in java

Tags: java, json, date, javafx

So am parsing json and sometimes the string I receive which contains the date comes full(dd-mm-yyyy) , and sometimes I only receive yyyy which I dont seem to able to convert to date ,so if anyone can help

Comment: If you check string size and skip it when its only 4, sounds good?

Comment: How are you parsing it? Using any libraries? If you are just using a regular stream parser then you would detect the type of date and if it's just a year you can use the appropriate constructor instead of trying to parse the yyyy directly into a Date.

Comment: Also perhaps showing the code and an example json would help here.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari Avoid using `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and possibly also `Year`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to process yyyy-mm and yyyy in java8 using DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893772/how-to-process-yyyy-mm-and-yyyy-in-java8-using-datetimeformatter)

Comment: Theres 2 parts to that problem two, there is 2 different date classes even in legacy. Also I do agree but sometimes the code base is already using Date heavily and didn't want to assume immediately that that was not the case.

Comment: So you assumed it *was* the case? @OmarAbdelBari IMHO that’s worse. Also even if it were, I’d still suggest not using `Date` for this bit.

Comment: Yea but if we were following the same train of thought then I'm surprised that you would suggest `LocalDate` over `ZonedDate` without having further information on the requirements.

Comment: I’d check the length of the string. If 4 then `Year.parse(yourString).atMonthDay(MonthDay.of(Month.DECEMBER, 31))` (substitute your desired day). Otheriwse `LocalDate.parse(yourString, someAppropriateDateTimeFormatter)`.

Answer (score 4):

As per your business requirement, you can default the month and the day-of-month to the required value using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting` e.g. in the following code, I have defaulted the month and the day-of-month to that of today:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(parseToDate("10-10-2020"));
        System.out.println(parseToDate("2020"));
    }

    static LocalDate parseToDate(String str) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .appendPattern("[dd-MM-uuuu][uuuu]")
                                        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, today.getMonthValue())
                                        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, today.getDayOfMonth())                                       
                                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-10
2020-12-12
```

**Note:** The pattern, `[dd-MM-uuuu][uuuu]` has two optional patterns, `dd-MM-uuuu` and `uuuu`.